# SQL Stored Procedure with Dynamic Column Names

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to generate a SQL statement that dynamically get column names from the database based on a filter. 
We have a table with about 50 columns with a prefix on each column to signify which "set" it applies to. I have created an Query that runs fine in SQL Management Studio, but as I would like to use the results in a .Net application as well as a Web application, it would be great to have a Stored Procedure or something similar that I can call for the results. I know i can manually specify the columns in my query, but I would like to try and do this dynamically columns may get added. The query I have worked out is below, what would be the best way to store this in my SQL server so that I can use it as required?

```
DECLARE @ColumnList AS Varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @StartDate as Date
DECLARE @EndDate as Date
DECLARE @DepartmentID as Varchar(10)
DECLARE @ColumnFilter as Varchar(3)

SET @StartDate = '2015-01-01' 
SET @EndDate = '2015-05-01'
SET @DepartmentID = 'GMC'
SET @ColumnFilter = 'GM'

SELECT @ColumnList =  COALESCE(@ColumnList, ',') + c.name+',' FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tblDetails') AND c.Name LIKE @ColumnFilter + '%'

SET @ColumnList = Left(@ColumnList,Len(@ColumnList)-1)

DECLARE @Template AS Varchar(max)
SET @Template = 'SELECT [RecordID]
      ,[DateRecord]
      ,[DepartmentID]
      ,[Shift]
      ,[ShiftLength]
      ,[ShiftType]
      ,[Active]
      ,[Comment]
      {ColumnList}
  FROM [Data_Warehouse].[dbo].[tblDetails]
  WHERE DateRecord >= ''{StartDate}'' AND DateRecord <= ''{EndDate}'' AND DepartmentID = ''{DepartmentID}''
  ORDER BY DateRecord'

SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{ColumnList}', @ColumnList) 
SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{StartDate}', @StartDate) 
SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{EndDate}', @EndDate) 
SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{DepartmentID}', @DepartmentID ) 

EXEC (@Template)
```

Comment: What do you do with the result in your web app? Is it a report that you simply display for the users in a datagrid?

Comment: Hi Peter, I am just displaying the data in a datagrid for users to see and export as required. I can add this directly in my .NET code and able to get the results, but would perfer to not have to have multiple copies of the code floating in different applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your query in a procedure just as it is. Then you can execute it from from your app/web and get a DataTable as the result. When you bind the DataTable to the DataGrid it should automatically render the columns in the DataGrid

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDynamicReport

     @StartDate as Date
    ,@EndDate as Date
    ,@DepartmentID as Varchar(10)
    ,@ColumnFilter as Varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ColumnList AS Varchar(MAX)

    SELECT @ColumnList =  COALESCE(@ColumnList, ',') + c.name+',' FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tblDetails') AND c.Name LIKE @ColumnFilter + '%'

    SET @ColumnList = Left(@ColumnList,Len(@ColumnList)-1)

    DECLARE @Template AS Varchar(max)
    SET @Template = 'SELECT [RecordID]
          ,[DateRecord]
          ,[DepartmentID]
          ,[Shift]
          ,[ShiftLength]
          ,[ShiftType]
          ,[Active]
          ,[Comment]
          {ColumnList}
      FROM [dbo].[tblDetails]
      WHERE DateRecord >= ''{StartDate}'' AND DateRecord <= ''{EndDate}'' AND DepartmentID = ''{DepartmentID}''
      ORDER BY DateRecord'

    SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{ColumnList}', @ColumnList) 
    SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{StartDate}', @StartDate) 
    SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{EndDate}', @EndDate) 
    SET @Template = REPLACE(@Template, '{DepartmentID}', @DepartmentID ) 

    EXEC (@Template);

END

GO
-- Execute it like this
EXEC dbo.GetDynamicReport 
    @StartDate = '2015-06-03 06:38:07',
    @EndDate = '2015-06-03 06:38:07',
    @DepartmentID = 'abc',
    @ColumnFilter = 'GM'
```

Calling the procedure

```
public static DataTable CallReportProcedure(string connectionString, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string departmentID, string columnFilter)
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDynamicReport", conn) 
        { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure} )
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", departmentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnFilter", columnFilter);

        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Then if you really need to know information about the columns you can inspect the resulting DataTable

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "localhost";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "peter";
            builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

            var resultTable = p.CallReportProcedure(connectionString, new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 5, 1), "GMC", "GM");
            // Bind the resultTable to your DataGrid

            // If you need to know the column names then you can loop through the Columns of the resultTable
            foreach (DataColumn col in resultTable.Columns)
            {
                // Print the names of the columns from the result
                Console.WriteLine(col.ColumnName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I tried initially to run it from a linked server, but for some reason i wasn't able to get the column list from the linked server. Adding it on the server that has the table worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view with just the columns you want for that query. when the columns you want in the query change, you just update the view, and viola, all your apps now get the new column you want. You just have to make sure your apps can deal with different potential columns coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Good solution is to use view for that.

Another option to use function but we can't update function after creation.
Here an example of that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION V_GetWarehouse (@StartDate Date,@EndDate Date,@DepartmentID  varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
 SELECT [RecordID]
  ,[DateRecord]
  ,[DepartmentID]
  ,[Shift]
  ,[ShiftLength]
  ,[ShiftType]
  ,[Active]
  ,[Comment]      
FROM [Data_Warehouse].[dbo].[tblDetails]
 WHERE DateRecord >= @StartDate AND DateRecord <= @EndDate AND DepartmentID=@DepartmentID
```

So use View instead of function.

There is another best way to create a new procedure rather view.
Here an example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetGenrealResult
 @ColumnName text,
 @TableName varchar(1000),
 @StartDate Date,
 @EndDate Date,
 @DepartmentID  varchar(10)
  AS
enter code here
        BEGIN

     declare @DateRecordCol char(10)='DateRecord',
      @DepartmentIDCol char(12)='DepartmentID' 
     Select @ColumnName from @TableName where @DateRecordCol >= @StartDate AND @DateRecordCol <= @EndDate AND @DepartmentIDCol =@DepartmentID
    END
```

Execute this.

```
   EXEC sp_GetGenrealResult '[RecordID],[DateRecord],  [DepartmentID]', '[Data_Warehouse].[dbo].  [tblDetails]' , '2015-01-01', '2015-05-01' ,'GMC'
```